# JavaScript functions put in event loop

Tags: javascript, function

In JavaScript, there are two types of functions.

1. Type-1  -> which are executed immediately in the stack. Eg: console.log()
2. Type-2  -> which are not executed right away; but put in the event loop. Once 
             the event has occurred, then the callback parameter(another 
             function) will be placed in the message queue and then into the 
             stack and finally executed.

   Eg: setTimeOut(function(){console.log("print")} , 1000);

When the above line is encountered by the runtime, it is immediately placed in even loop; after 1000 mili seconds pass then the callback function is pushed into message queue. When the stack becomes free,the callback function is executed.

Can anyone please point me to a place where the list of such functions (like: setTimeOut() ) are available in JavaScript.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your problem? What is your question? What you mean? Please, learn [ask] and [edit] your question to be clear about your needs

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference

Comment: I am afraid why it is not still clear and the question has been put on hold. I believe who ever knows the event loop in JavaScript,  can easy understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

The following async callbacks exist in JS:

```
  promise.then(/*async*/).catch(/*async*/)
```

The Web API also adds a few:

```
 setTimeout(/*async*/, 0)
 setInterval(/*async*/, 0)
 requestAnimationFrame(/*async*/)

 element.onclick = /*async*/;
 element.addEventListener("click", /*async*/)
 // ... all those other handlers.
```

> [synchrously] e.g. `console.log()`

Thats a bad example. Every function call will be executed immeadiately, it can't get executed asynchronously. A callback however can get called back now (synchronous) e.g.:

```
 [1, 2, 3].forEach(console.log)
```

or it can get called asynchronously:

```
 fetch("http://stackoverflow.com").then(console.log);
```

Every callback might get called back asynchronously, however that only works if the code calling back was called back itself, so if it is based on one of the native callback executors listed above.